# Excel: import named ranges given from "Paste List"

Tags: excel

I defined several named ranges in my `Excel` document and copy the list as a backup with `F3` "Paste List".

The list of named ranges is then written in my Excel file, one column for the name and one column for the named range formula. So far so good.

1. Where is the option to *"Import"* the named ranges from the list in Excel
2. What is the point of "Paste List" if the import function is missing?

Comment: btw, another way to 'list' the reference cell in a named range : `=CELL("address",name)`

Answer (score 0):

Solution : duplicate the empty version on the file.

```
Save as > empty all sheet > use as new file
```

The defined name should be still intact.

Please share if it works/not on your case. ( :

Comment: Actually, I what I am trying to implement is a small version control of the named ranges. Obviously, Excel's developers got that in mind when they implemented the Export feature. Is there any way to apply previous list of formulas in my current Excel file? From my current understanding, this is a missing feature, but it can probably be implemented in VBA.

Comment: it can be implemented in VBA >> https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-named-range/ | vba is not really my strong point, thus I refrain from typing it as a proper answer.. (the is no vba tag, that's why the attempt..) /(^_^)